# Magento command line

Tags: upgrade, update-handle, command-line

I'm trying to update my magento from command line.
I changed mage permissions to 755

```
 chmod 755 mage
```

Then I launched mage-setup

```
./mage mage-setup
```

But when I try other commands the following error occurs

```
Please initialize Magento Connect installer by running:
./mage mage-setup
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you are missing one part of the mage-setup command. Try using the command `./mage mage-setup .`. Notice the `.` at the end, this should tell the setup to use the current directory.

After this is done you can continue the upgrade with the normal commands.

```
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage sync
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Comment: The dot don't solved my problem
See here: http://it.tinypic.com/r/behc3p/8

Answer (score 1):

In "mage" file, replace/uncomment
`#MAGE_PHP_BIN="php"`

with:
`MAGE_PHP_BIN="php-cli"`

The mage console require php in cli mode, and a lot of time "php" point to cgi and it will stop working.

If you don't have php cli version you can always modify mage.php.
putting:

```
if (!defined('STDIN'))
{
    define('STDIN', fopen('php://stdin', 'r'));
}
if (!defined('STDOUT'))
{
    define('STDOUT', fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
}
if (!defined('STDERR'))
{
    define('STDERR', fopen('php://stderr', 'w'));
}
```

anywhere before:
`if (defined('STDIN') && defined('STDOUT') && (defined('STDERR'))) {`